# How to Solve a Calculus of Variation Problem with Terminal Conditions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I've been struggling to solve calculus of variation problems with terminal conditions. The current textbook i'm using for my course seems to only tangentially touch upon the methodology. Here is one problem for example:

min $\int_{0}^{1}(10-16x-8x^2-\frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2)dt$

with the initial condition $x(0) = 0$ and in each case of the terminal condition:

1. $x(1) \in [0,1]$
2. $x(1) \leq 0$
3. $x(1) \geq 1$

How would I go about solving a problem like this? After I get the ODE and isolate for the constant A, i'm not sure how to continue

Comment: Perhaps you should address the terminal condition first, then solve the problem?

Comment: Once you get the ODE equation are you getting the first derivative of x(t) then setting it equal to each condition separately?

Comment: Sorry, I will remove my comment, it was a bad joke.

Comment: @copper.hat Keep the joke

Comment: @Mattos: :-) ${}{}{}$

Comment: Is there some prescribed initial condition here?

Comment: @copper.hat yes there is, I just edited the post to include it, my apologies

Comment: The Euler-Lagrange equation is $\ddot x-16(x+1)=0$ so that with $x(0)=0$ one gets solutions $x(t)=[\cosh(4x)-1]+B\sinh(4x)$.

Comment: @LutzL and then given that solution I just set x(t) = to each terminal condition, correct?

Comment: The question is, is the right boundary free? Then you get to explore $\dot x(1)=0$ and if that gives a solution with $x(1)$ inside the interval. Then compare the value of the integral with the solution for the interval endpoints.

Comment: Are you sure there is a solution? At first glance I would guess that there are solutions of arbitrarily small cost.

Comment: The Euler-Lagrange mechanism only finds the stationary points of the functional. Next one would have to check if they are local minima, maxima or saddle points, and then check where the global minimum is. At this stage it is the same as if one had a simple scalar function and wanted to compute the extrema on an interval.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $x(t) = \begin{cases}Kt,& t\in [0, {1 \over 2}] \\ 
K(1-t), & t \in [{1 \over 2},1]\end{cases} $, then $x(0) = x(1) = 0$,
and the cost is $J(x) = -{1 \over 3}(5 K^2+12K-30)$. By choosing $K$ arbitrarily large we
can make the cost as small as we want.

It is straightforward to see that we can make small adjustments to $x$ at the midpoint so that $x$ is smooth, however this complicates the analysis and
obscures the point.

It follows that 1., 2. have no solution. (Assuming that my computations were correct, a
big assumption.)